# ¿Cómo imprimir en pantalla en intervalos de tiempo con Python?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de escribir con Python un programa que imprima en pantalla elementos de una lista en intervalos de dos segundos. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
a=0.0
b=0.0
c=0.0

i=0

import time

a=time.time()

while i<5:
    b=time.time()
    c=b-a
    if c>=2.0:
        a=time.time()
        i=i+1
        print (i)
    else:
        continue
```

Funciona, pero ¿hay alguna forma más directa o eficiente de hacer esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y si usas `sleep()`?

```
i=0

import time

while i<5:
    print (i)
    i=i+1        
    # tiempo en segundos
    time.sleep(5)
```